# I get an "Error in 1:x : NA/NaN argument"

Tags: r

I'm using data:
www.policyuncertainty.com/media/All_Daily_Policy_Data.csv

https://economicpolicyuncertaintyinchina.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/2/7/122762465/cnepu_daily_14_apr_2020_updated.xlsx

I deleted 0's from the China's data (period 2020-01-01 to 2020-04-13).
this is my code, when I try to forecast ADL "forecast_ADL" I only get NA_real_, can someone help?

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library("dplyr")
cnepu <-
  readxl::read_xlsx('/Users/agne/downloads/cnepu_daily_14_apr_2020_new.xlsx')
usaepu <-
  read.csv('/Users/agne/downloads/All_Daily_Policy_Data.csv')
install.packages("stringr")
library("stringr")
install.packages("lubridate")
library("lubridate")

#Selecting a time period
date_cn <- cnepu[cnepu$date > '2020-01-01', ]
us_epu_filtered <- usaepu %>%
  select(year, day, month, daily_policy_index) %>%
  mutate(date1 = str_c(year, month, day, sep = "-"),
         date = ymd(date1)) %>%
  filter(date >= as.Date("2020-01-01") &
           date <= as.Date("2020-04-13"))
cn_epu_filterd <- cnepu %>%
  filter(date > as.Date("2020-01-01"))

#Selected time period EPU's
us_epu <- us_epu_filtered$daily_policy_index
cn_epu <- cn_epu_filterd$CNEPU_Daily
date <- us_epu_filtered$date

#ADL(2,2)
install.packages("dynlm")
library("dynlm")
us_epu_ts <- ts(us_epu)
cn_epu_ts <- ts(cn_epu)
level_us <- as.numeric(us_epu[-1])
level_cn <- as.numeric(cn_epu[-1])
us_forecast_new_ts <-
  dynlm(ts(us_epu) ~ L(ts(us_epu)) + L(ts(us_epu), 2) +
          L(ts(cn_epu)) + L(ts(cn_epu), 2))

#Forecast
library(urca)
summary(ur.df(
  us_epu,
  type = "trend",
  lags = 2,
  selectlags = "Fixed"
))
library("lmtest")
N <- 104
forecast_ADL <-
  c(coef(us_forecast_new_ts) %*% c(1, level_us[N - 1], level_us[N -
                                                                  2], level_cn[N -
                                                                                 1], level_cn[N - 2]))

#BIC calculation
order <-
  1:10
BIC <- function(model) {
  ssr <- sum(model$residuals ^ 2)
  t <- length(model$residuals)
  npar <- length(model$coef)
  return(round(
    c(
      "p" = npar - 1,
      "BIC" = log(ssr / t) + npar * log(t) / t,
      "R2" = summary(model)$r.squared
    ),
    4
  ))

}

bics <- sapply(order, function(x)
  "AR" = BIC(dynlm(
    us_epu_ts ~ L(us_epu_ts, 1:x) + L(cn_epu_ts, 1:x), date
  )))

bics[, which.min(bics[2,])]
length(us_forecast_new_ts$coefficients)
```

Comment: Hi, you should make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, try to reproduce your error with data that is available for everyone in R such as (`iris` or `mtcars`)